# Deep Granularity of @PreAuthorize Throwed exception

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a secure method in My service :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('TRANSACTION') and hasRole('INIT_TRANSACTION') and @amountValidatorServiceBean.isAmountValidForCurrentUser(#amount)" )
public void initTransaction(Amount amount){
....
....
}
```

This work well , but when it's fail it always throw an org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException Exception .

I want to have a more deep granularity of the throwed exception :

TransactionRightException // InitTransactionRightException and AmountTransactionException .

Is there a clean way of doing this combined with @PreAuthorize.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi @Nabil. Have you tried to throw your custom exceptions directly from `isAmountValidForCurrentUser` method? instead of returning false?

Comment: I will try that but this don't resolve my problem because i want to make a difference between exception when user don't have the Role TRANSACTION and when the user don't have the Role INIT_TRANSACTION ... Any idea , Thanks for your help

Comment: I think for you case declarative way with annotations is not enoug flexible. Try to remove annotation and try to do all your custom checks directly in the code. It will be much easier to do IMHO.